# How do I get see the zero value in a Google Sheets Chart?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

In this list of "Dogs on tap" we have Shitzu but none on tap. The charting tool in Google Sheets doesn't even acknowledge that we have Shitzu. Nevertheless, I would like the fact that we have the breed (even if we have none on tap at the moment) reflected in the pie chart.

[image: Data and chart]

I have read about `sliceVisibilityThreshold` and have [fiddled](https://jsfiddle.net/icc97/smcukL73/) with someone else's work such that if I change

```js
        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };
```

to

```js
        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          sliceVisibilityThreshold : 0
        };
```

the legend will at least acknowledge the zero value. Now how do I get that same behaviour into my Google Sheets chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can use a "close to zero" value:

[image]

To take this further you could use and `onEdit` Apps Script simple trigger to change all `0` values to `0.00000...01` while keeping the display at only a few significant figures, so it displays as 0 too.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  let s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive() // This line can be deleted after authorization
  let rng = e.range
  if (e.value == 0){
    rng.setValue(0.00000000000001)
  }
}
```

Run this function once in the editor to grant the authorizations necessary. Then it should automatically replace all 0 values behind the scenes, and will show up in the chart after a short delay:

[image]

Ideally there would be an option, though it could be argued that if something occupies 0% of the pie, it shouldn't show up in a pie chart. In any case, you can always make a feature request if you think it should have its own option.

#### Reference

- [Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: "Wow" doesn't quite cut it. But ... umm ... wow!

Comment: Yeah this is pretty ridiculous. For line charts, it won't chart the value if it's zero.